# Using Ajax to get and show mysqli query results

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I'm practicing Ajax by making an app that checks the content of a database table and inserts it into my page asynchronously, only the first row of the table is printing and I'm not sure why. This is my code:

index.php - Here is where I create the page with an empty space in #result_table that should get filled by the table fetched by places.php

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id="showPlaces" name="showPlaces">Mesas</button>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nombre</th><th>Piso</th><th>Cliente</th><th>Mesero</th><th>Area</th><th>Estado</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="result_table">

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
</div>
```

places.php - Here I make the query and return(?) the data

```
    <?php

include("con.php");
mysqli_select_db("unicentaopos", $c);
$result = mysqli_query($c,"SELECT * FROM places");
while ($places = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $places ['NAME']."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $places ['FLOOR']."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $places ['CUSTOMER']."</td>";
    if (!$places['WAITER']) {
        echo "<td>" . "VACIO" . "</td>";    
    } else {            
        echo "<td>". $places ['WAITER']."</td>";
    }           
    echo "<td>". $places ['AREA']."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $places ['ESTADO']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
} 
mysqli_free_result($result);
?>
```

script.js - Here I use jQuery to make the Http request

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#showPlaces').click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url: 'places.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(result){
                $('#result_table').html(result);
            } // End of success function of ajax form
        }); // End of ajax call    

    });
});
```

con.php - Here I connect to the database

```
<?php
    $c = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","unicentaopos");// Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {   // Si hay error lo menciona en alerta.
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
                echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
                echo '</div>';
        } else {    // Si no hay error.

        }       
    ?>
```

I've been stuck on this for a while, could you guys help me pinpoint the problem? I guess it's either the way i'm returning the data from places.php, or I'm making a mistake in the connection, wich would be weird since that very same code worked for a simple example I did a while ago.
Please remember, I'm new to Ajax so anything you can tell me that helps me improve will be very welcome.

- Fixed it with help of the comments and edited the post with the working code.

Comment: Have you watched the request/response in the browser's console?

Comment: Your button is inside  an `<a>` with href...you sure page isn't reloading? That setup doesn't make sense. When clicking the button you are also clicking the parent `<a>`

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the reply! I fixed that and now the first row (and only the first) is showing. I updated the post to reflect the change

Comment: @JayBlanchard The Developer tools console is not showing anything, is there another one I should be checking?

Comment: So you are getting ajax html inserted into the table now? not clear what `only first row` means. How many rows are you expecting?

Comment: @charlietfl There are eight entries on the table, the first one is showing correctly, the rest are not showing at all. Maybe something wrong with the while ($places = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

Comment: dont seem to have an opening `<tr>` tag...so if that's true html is invalid

Comment: @charlietfl Oh come on! How could I not catch that?! I fixed it and now it works perfectly. Thank you charlietfl! I can't seem to find the "answered" button to mark the question acordingly. Did it move? It's usually a green tick besides the comment, right? Or is it only on answers (not comments)?

Comment: there are no answers...just comments